# Equal Height of rows in two dynamically created tables,using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatables

According to my requirement I need to create two different tables, which will have same number of rows but will have different data. First table will have Item Information and second table will have consolidated information about the items, for example how many Items sold in last week, how many are there in inventory etc.
I am using jQuery datatable for first because, I will be needed sorting to sort items, so its easy with jquery datatable. second table is normal table which will be created once all items will be loaded into first table.

here is the example :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var displayShopColumns = [
        "QOH",
        "PO",
        "Sold LW",
        "QTY",
        "Cost"
    ];
     var shopColumns = [
        "qoh",
        "po",
        "sold",
        "qty",
        ""
    ];

        var arr=[
        {'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},
      {'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},
            {'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},
      {'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},
      {'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},
      {'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},

    ]
        var tbl = $('#tblItems').DataTable({
            data:arr,
            bStateSave: false,
            columns: [
                { data: "itemCread" },
                {
                    data: "imageUrl",
                    render: function (file_id) {
                        //console.log(file_id);
                        return file_id ?
                            '<img class="gridImg" src="' + file_id + '"/>' :
                            null;
                    },
                    title: "Img"
                },
                { data: "description" },
                { data: "manSKU" },
                { data: "moq" },
                { data: "cost" },
                { data: "Retail" },
                { data: "margin" },
                { data: "Category" },
                { data: "subCat1" },
                { data: "subCat2" },
            ],
            select: true,
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": false,
            "searching": false,
            fnInitComplete: function (oSettings, json) {
              //  window.setLocalStorage('de',JSON.stringify(json));
                //loadShopItemsTemp(json);
                loadOtherTable(oSettings.aiDisplay);
            }
        });
        
        
         function loadOtherTable(response){
        
                $('#ddd').html("");
                var rows = "", mainCols="", headerCols = "";
                <!-- var name = "<tr><td colspan='5'style='text-align: center;'>001 - SoHa Kahala</td></tr>"; -->
                <!-- var PONum = "<tr><td >PO#</td><td colspan='4'>001-test1</td></tr>"; -->
                <!-- var sum = "<tr><td colspan='3'>Total <span>64 Units</span></td><td colspan='2'>$150.00</td></tr>"; -->
                <!-- mainCols = name + PONum + sum; -->
                var headerHeight = $('#tblItems thead').find('tr').eq(0).height();
                displayShopColumns.forEach((v, i) => {                
                    headerCols += "<th> " + v + "</th>";
                });
                //common rows
                //var response = JSON.parse(res);
                for (let row = 0; row < response.length; row++) {
                    var height = $('#tblItems tbody').find('tr').eq(row).height();
                    var isChange = true;
                    if (row > 0 && (row) / 3 == 0) {
                        if (isChange) {
                            isChange = false;
                            height = height - 3;
                        } else{
                            isChange = true;
                            height = height + 3;
                        }                
                    }
           
                    rows += "<tr style='height:"+height+"px'>";

                    shopColumns.forEach((val, index) => {
                        var colVal = response[row][val];
                        if (val == "qty") {                    
                            rows += "<td class='td-padding' style='padding:0;'><input style='height:" + height +"px ;' class='input-cost' type='text'/></td>";
                        } else {
                            
                            rows += "<td class='td-padding'>" + row + "</td>";
                        }
                    });
                    rows += "</tr>";
                }

                var tabltemp = "<table id='T' class='table-bordered'style='background-color:#f0f0f0;table-layout:fixed;'><thead>" + mainCols + "<tr style='height:" + headerHeight + "px;text-align:center'> " + headerCols + "</tr></thead > <tbody>" + rows + "</tbody></table > ";

                if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#T')) {
                    table = $('#T').DataTable();
                    table.destroy();
                }
                $('#ddd').append(tabltemp);
        }
})
```

```css
.gridImg{
            width: 30px;
            height:30px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</head>
<body>
   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
             <table id="tblItems" class="table-bordered" style="display:block;table-layout:fixed;float:left">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Item Created</th>
                          <th>Image</th>
                          <th>Item</th>
                          <th>Manf SKU</th>
                          <th>MOQ</th>
                          <th>Cost</th>
                          <th>Retail</th>
                          <th>Margin</th>
                          <th>Cateogry</th>
                          <th>Sub Cat1</th>
                          <th>Sub Cat2</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  </tbody>
              </table>  
            </div>
            <div id="ddd" class="col-md-3">
            
            
            </div>
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you were pretty close. It seems that the culprit was the textbox you're including in your second table. I only had to make 2 changes to your original code:

1. Add this CSS rule `tr { height: 50px; }` to be sure both, thead and tbody rows have the same height.
2. This is the most important change. **I'm subtracting 2 pixels** from your textbox's height. Because it seems that it's default border size it's equivalent to 1 pixel, and as it have a top and bottom border, it was adding 2 extra pixels to your height variable.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var displayShopColumns = [
        "QOH",
        "PO",
        "Sold LW",
        "QTY",
        "Cost"
    ];
     var shopColumns = [
        "qoh",
        "po",
        "sold",
        "qty",
        ""
    ];

        var arr=[
        {'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},
      {'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},
            {'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},
      {'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},
      {'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},
      {'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},{'itemCread':'202/09/01','imageUrl':'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300','description':'test1','manSKU':'654789','moq':'10','cost':'12.36','Retail':'12.36','margin':'0','Category':'Test Category 1','subCat1':'Sub Category 1','subCat2':'Sub Category 2'},

    ]
        var tbl = $('#tblItems').DataTable({
            data:arr,
            bStateSave: false,
            columns: [
                { data: "itemCread" },
                {
                    data: "imageUrl",
                    render: function (file_id) {
                        //console.log(file_id);
                        return file_id ?
                            '<img class="gridImg" src="' + file_id + '"/>' :
                            null;
                    },
                    title: "Img"
                },
                { data: "description" },
                { data: "manSKU" },
                { data: "moq" },
                { data: "cost" },
                { data: "Retail" },
                { data: "margin" },
                { data: "Category" },
                { data: "subCat1" },
                { data: "subCat2" },
            ],
            select: true,
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": false,
            "searching": false,
            fnInitComplete: function (oSettings, json) {
              //  window.setLocalStorage('de',JSON.stringify(json));
                //loadShopItemsTemp(json);
                loadOtherTable(oSettings.aiDisplay);
            }
        });
        
        
         function loadOtherTable(response){
        
                $('#ddd').html("");
                var rows = "", mainCols="", headerCols = "";
                <!-- var name = "<tr><td colspan='5'style='text-align: center;'>001 - SoHa Kahala</td></tr>"; -->
                <!-- var PONum = "<tr><td >PO#</td><td colspan='4'>001-test1</td></tr>"; -->
                <!-- var sum = "<tr><td colspan='3'>Total <span>64 Units</span></td><td colspan='2'>$150.00</td></tr>"; -->
                <!-- mainCols = name + PONum + sum; -->
                var headerHeight = $('#tblItems thead').find('tr').eq(0).height();
                displayShopColumns.forEach((v, i) => {                
                    headerCols += "<th> " + v + "</th>";
                });
                //common rows
                //var response = JSON.parse(res);
                for (let row = 0; row < response.length; row++) {
                    var height = $('#tblItems tbody').find('tr').eq(row).height();
                    var isChange = true;
                    if (row > 0 && (row) / 3 == 0) {
                        if (isChange) {
                            isChange = false;
                            height = height - 3;
                        } else{
                            isChange = true;
                            height = height + 3;
                        }                
                    }
           
                    rows += "<tr style='height:"+height+"px'>";

                    shopColumns.forEach((val, index) => {
                        var colVal = response[row][val];
                        if (val == "qty") {                    
                            rows += "<td class='td-padding' style='padding:0;'><input style='height:" + (height - 2) +"px ;' class='input-cost' type='text'/></td>";
                        } else {
                            
                            rows += "<td class='td-padding'>" + row + "</td>";
                        }
                    });
                    rows += "</tr>";
                }

                var tabltemp = "<table id='T' class='table-bordered'style='background-color:#f0f0f0;table-layout:fixed;'><thead>" + mainCols + "<tr style='height:" + headerHeight + "px;text-align:center'> " + headerCols + "</tr></thead > <tbody>" + rows + "</tbody></table > ";

                if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#T')) {
                    table = $('#T').DataTable();
                    table.destroy();
                }
                $('#ddd').append(tabltemp);
        }
})
```

```css
.gridImg {
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
}

tr { height: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</head>
<body>
   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
             <table id="tblItems" class="table-bordered" style="display:block;table-layout:fixed;float:left">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Item Created</th>
                          <th>Image</th>
                          <th>Item</th>
                          <th>Manf SKU</th>
                          <th>MOQ</th>
                          <th>Cost</th>
                          <th>Retail</th>
                          <th>Margin</th>
                          <th>Cateogry</th>
                          <th>Sub Cat1</th>
                          <th>Sub Cat2</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  </tbody>
              </table>  
            </div>
            <div id="ddd" class="col-md-3">
            
            
            </div>
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```